# Table to matrix conversion for linear model

Tags: r, matrix, integer, type-conversion, typeof

I need to convert a 3-column table called 'Abund' into a matrix. The data specify plot, species and abundance and are of type 'integer'. I currently use the following code to convert the table to a matrix:

```
AbundMat <- acast(Abund, plot~species, value.var="occurrence", fun.aggregate=length)
```

The matrix is of type 'integer'. In a subsequent analysis using the function 'manyglm' I get an error message. When I compare my data to an example dataset (which I can run just fine), the only difference that I notice is that the example matrix is of type 'double'. I am not sure whether this is be the cause for the error message. How can I convert my matrix to type 'double'?

This is a reproducible subset of the file 'Abund':

```
structure(list(plot = structure(c(47L, 47L, 48L, 51L, 53L, 54L), .Label = c("A01", "A02", "A03", "A04", "A05", "A06", "A07", "A08", "A09", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", "A18", "A19", "A20", "A21", "A22", "A23", "A24", "A25", "A26", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A30", "A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38", "A39", "A40", "A41", "A42", "A43", "A44", "A45", "A46", "A47", "A48", "A49", "B01", "B02", "B03", "B04", "B05", "B06", "B07", "B08", "B09", "B10", "B11", "B12", "B13", "B14", "B15", "B16", "B17", "B18", "B19", "B20", "B21", "B22", "B23", "B24", "B25", "B26", "B27", "B28", "B29", "B30", "B31", "B32", "B33", "B34", "B35", "B36", "B37", "B38", "B39", "B40", "B41", "B42", "B43", "B44", "B45", "C01", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C05", "C06", "C07", "C08", "C09", "C10", "C11", "C12", "C13", "C14", "C15", "C16", "C17", "C18", "C19", "C20", "C21", "C22", "C23", "C24", "C25", "C26", "C27", "C28", "C29", "C30", "C31", "C32", "C33", "C34", "C35", "C36", "C37", "C38", "C39", "C40", "C41", "C42", "C43", "C44", "C45"), class = "factor"), 
species = structure(c(46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L), .Label = c("sp1", 
"sp10", "sp11", "sp12", "sp13", "sp14", "sp15", "sp16", "sp17", 
"sp18", "sp19", "sp2", "sp20", "sp21", "sp22", "sp23", "sp24", 
"sp25", "sp26", "sp27", "sp28", "sp29", "sp3", "sp30", "sp31", 
"sp32", "sp33", "sp34", "sp35", "sp36", "sp37", "sp38", "sp39", 
"sp4", "sp40", "sp41", "sp42", "sp43", "sp44", "sp45", "sp46", 
"sp47", "sp48", "sp49", "sp5", "sp50", "sp51", "sp52", "sp53", 
"sp54", "sp55", "sp56", "sp57", "sp58", "sp59", "sp6", "sp60", 
"sp61", "sp62", "sp7", "sp8", "sp9"), class = "factor"), 
occurrence = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("plot", "species", "occurrence"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You can use `as.numeric(data)` and it will make your integers into floating point numerics which is the R version of doubles. But based on your data here, there will still be a problem. R requires that ALL data in a matrix is of the same type, either character OR integer OR numeric...but not mixed. It might be best to turn the table into a data frame `abundMat<-data.frame(abundMat)` then convert the integer column `abundMat$occurence<- as.numeric(abundMat$occurence)` that will get your data into the right structure with the right types.

Comment: `AbundMat[] <- as.double(AbundMat)`

Comment: Thank you! Turning the 'occurrence' column from integer to numeric works. However, using acast() to create the matrix, 'AbundMat' still has type=integer (and not the required type=double). You did mean converting the 'occurrence' column in table 'Abund', correct? When I try the 2nd approach to apply as.double() to the matrix 'AbundMat', I do get type=double but now class=numeric (but should be class=matrix). Also, attributes() is now NULL. Would you have any further advice?